# Chrome unloads symbols occasionally and displays odd characters

Tags: html, css, utf-8

Occasionally chrome unloads a symbol and displays something else instead, seemingly randomly.
I have an example right now on a bulleted list. I have set custom bullets with `content: "\2022";` set on the `:before` element.

It works most of the time, though occasionally it appears as different characters. I’ve experienced this on and off in chrome for years, it’s always worse with custom webfonts.

I’ve tried declaring UTF-8 encoding in the stylesheet and HTML and checking the file types. Nothing seems to fix it and stack overflow has similar issues but no working solution.

I can’t deliberately make it happen, it just happens randomly when I come back to a tab after a period of inactivity. Or on maybe 1 in 30 refreshes.

[image]
[image]

Example: https://codepen.io/jhobden600/pen/abZdYWM

Comment: Please inspect the element; in case of _your own_ page share a [mcve] . Otherwise, ask at https://superuser.com/

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Chrome, and there's not much you can do about it unless you are in the Chrome development team

Comment: @JosefZ thanks, please see codepen added.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Chrome's [auto-encoding detection](https://superuser.com/a/1160292/376602) as `â¢` looks like a text appearance (bytes as CP1252 characters) of UTF-8 encoded bullet • (Unicode U+2022 = UTF-8 byte sequence 0xE2,0x80,0xA2).

Comment: @JosefZ It's definitely a bug, if I use an extension to change the Character Encoding to something else and change it back to UTF-8 again it fixes itself.